# Do I have to sychronize timers with the system clock?

Tags: c#, timer, clock

I'm going to create my own scheduler and for this, I wanted to use either the `System.Timers.Timer` or the `Observable.Interval` method.

But there is one thing that I'm not sure about. Are such timers always in sync with the system clock?

By in sync I mean that they tick exactly like the main clock and won't be late after a month or two or do I have to preriodically check if they are not too fast/slow and synchronize them again?

Comment: No, they will not be in sync, nor will they stay in sync once you do get them sync'd (for the first time). Think about what happens when your computer gets a new NTP date/time or when daylight savings happens.

Comment: The general advice is to get the elapsed time between ticks from the OS, without relying on the interval of the `Timer`.

Comment: Yes, they will be in sync.  The CLR uses SleepEx() under the hood to wait until the next timer is ready to fire, you can see it [being used here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L4641).  Clock adjustments from a time server are implemented by very small adjustments to the tick increment to slowly let the wall clock catch up to the new time, they work on sleeps as well.  It won't compensate for timezone changes and you have to be aware of daylight changes and power loss.  So you have one guy say "no" and one say "yes", good luck :)